# If $ a \mid bc $ then $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Prove or reject this statement:

> If $ a \mid bc $ then $\displaystyle \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \mid c$

Comment: Did you try it for couple of values?

Comment: @imranfat Yes and I think that's right

Comment: Still not sure if it is correct.

$$ a|bc \implies a = \frac{\gcd(a,c) \gcd(a,b)}{\gcd(\gcd(b,c),a)} \\
\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} = \frac{\gcd(a,c)}{\gcd(\gcd(b,c),a)} \implies \gcd(\gcd(b,c),a)|\gcd(a,c) \; \& \; \gcd(a,c)|c$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $a\mid bc$ and $(a,b)=1$ then $a\mid c$. Use this to show:

$$
\displaystyle  a \mid bc \implies \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \mid \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\times c \implies \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\mid c
$$
Because [$\gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752928).

Comment: Didn't you add the extra condition that $(a,b)=1$ to the question?

Comment: There is no assumption about $\gcd(a,b)$,this works for general $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let the highest power of prime $p$ that divides $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$ respectively

As $a|bc, A\le B+C\iff A-B\le C\  \  \  \ (1) $

Now, the highest power$(D)$  of prime $p$ that divides $\displaystyle \frac a{(a,b)}=A-$min$(A,B)$

If $A\ge B,D=A-B\le C$ by $(1)$

Else $D=A-A=0$ which is always $\le C$

Comment: But I think this neither prove nor reject it!

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, it proves that for all prime divisor of $c,$ the proposition is true, hence is the proposition

Comment: Is this correct: $a|bc \iff A-B\le C$ ?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, the sum of powers of any prime $p$ in $b,c$ must be $\ge$ the power that prime in $a$

Comment: Isn't $\gcd(a,b)$ a $\min(A,B)$ with regard to $p$?

Comment: @dtldarek, sorry for the mistake, rectified