# How many "distinct" polynomials functions are there mod $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

*(This sounds like a fairly natural question, but I couldn't find it asked on this site before…)*

Fix an integer $n$ as the modulus, and consider polynomials (with integer coefficients) modulo $n$.

For any polynomial $f$ and any fixed $k$, we have $f(x) + nx^k \equiv f(x) \pmod n$ for all integers $x$; thus any two polynomials with some coefficient differing by a multiple of $n$ are equivalent in the sense that they give the same value mod $n$ for any integer $x$ as input. So we can assume that each coefficient of $f$ is one of $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$.

When $n$ is prime, we know (from Fermat's little theorem) that $x^n \equiv x \pmod n$ for all integers $x$, which means any polynomial of degree $n$ or greater is equivalent (in the same sense as above) to a polynomial of lower degree. Even when $n$ is not prime, some such relationship probably exists; for example when $n=4$, we can see that $x^4 \equiv x^2 \pmod 4$. (I guess, though this may be wrong and I haven't checked it, that if the prime factorization of $n$ is $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$, then $x^n \equiv x^{n/(p_1p_2\cdots p_r)} \pmod n$.)

In any case, whenever $x \equiv y \pmod n$, we have $f(x) \equiv f(y) \pmod n$, so it is enough to consider the polynomial's values at $n$ consecutive integers say $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$. As there are at most $n$ distinct values it can have mod $n$ for each input $n$, there are at most $n^n$ distinct polynomials in this sense.

**The question**: How many distinct polynomials with integer coefficients are there mod $n$? Here, the meaning of "distinct" is that polynomials $f$ and $g$ are "distinct" if there exists at least one integer $x$ at which $f(x) \not\equiv g(x) \pmod n$. Or, using the terminology from what I found later (see below), we want the number of polynomial functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

---

That is the question, but of course before asking it here I tried a few things to find the answer myself, including writing the following program.

Define the "signature" (just a name I made up for writing this program: is there already a standard term for this?) of a polynomial $f$ as the tuple $(f(0), f(1), f(2), …, f(n-1))$ of its values at all $n$ points. We can count the number of distinct polynomials mod $n$ by keeping track of all the encountered signatures, as we start with the zero polynomial and successively add $ax^k$ for each $a$ from $0$ to $n-1$, for increasing $k$ until $x^k$ has the same signature as some already seen polynomial.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Adding the signatures of two polynomials mod n
def add(t1, t2):
    n = len(t1)
    assert n == len(t2)
    return tuple((t1[i] + t2[i]) % n for i in range(n))

def count(n):
    szero = tuple([0]*n)  # The signature of the zero polynomial
    seen = {szero}  # Only the zero polynomial has been seen
    k = 0
    sxk = tuple([1]*n)  # The signature of x^k
    while True:
        news = set()  # New signatures, by adding ax^k for some a
        saxk = szero
        for a in range(1, n):
            saxk = add(saxk, sxk)  # The signature of a*(x^k)
            for s in seen:
                newp = add(saxk, s)  # a*(x^k) + (smaller polynomial)
                if newp not in seen: news.add(newp)
        seen.update(news)
        # Now done with all polynomials of degree k
        k += 1
        sxk = tuple((sxk[i]*i) % n for i in range(n))
        if sxk in seen: break
    return len(seen)

print('n', '\t', 'count(n)')
for n in range(1, 11):  # Gets very slow for n=11
    print(n, '\t', count(n))
```

This prints:

```
n    count(n)
1    1
2    4
3    27
4    64
5    3125
6    108
7    823543
8    1024
9    19683
10   12500
```

The good thing about computing these small values is that there is the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), using which you can, to quote [Donald Knuth](https://youtu.be/BxQw4CdxLr8?t=1190), "compute your way into the literature". And accordingly, searching the OEIS for this sequence $1$, $4$, $27$, $64$, $3125$, $108$, $823543$, $1024$, $19683$ gives [A058067](http://oeis.org/A058067) described as "Number of polynomial functions from Z to Z/nZ" which is exactly our question. We also learn from that page that there's a formula

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}
$$

that fits the numbers we computed and (per that page) was first proved by Aubrey J. Kempner in 1921 in a two-part paper called "Polynomials and their residue systems" ([1](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1921-022-02/S0002-9947-1921-1501173-4/home.html), [2](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1921-022-03/S0002-9947-1921-1501174-6/home.html)), and by David Singmaster ([1974](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(74)90031-6)), and there's what appears to be a nice paper in 2000 by Manjul Bhargava called ["The Factorial Function and Generalizations"](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-factorial-function-and-generalizations) [PDF](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Hasse/00029890.di021346.02p0064l.pdf) that generalizes it (and maybe gives a shorter proof).

But I haven't read any of these papers as I ran out of my time budget for this (well, I exceeded it by writing up this question), and I hope someone can give a clear proof/derivation of the formula either using those papers or independently.

---

**Edit**: I read Bhargava's paper and understood it enough to [answer this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070413/205) below.

Comment: Closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n

Comment: @lhf Yes, I used the result from this question/answer to leave [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070878/205) at that question. :-) AFAICT it is the first complete answer at that question, but doesn't seem to have gotten any attention.

Comment: Also linking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789219/11619). IIRC the paper Carlitz (too bad I cannot find an exact reference) I mentioned there does discuss this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a proof based on the [article by Manjul Bhargava (2000)](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-factorial-function-and-generalizations): this article is nicely written and won a [Merten M. Hasse Prize](https://www.maa.org/programs-and-communities/member-communities/maa-awards/writing-awards/hasse-prizes) ("for a noteworthy expository paper appearing in an Association [MAA] publication, at least one of whose authors is a younger mathematician"). Though the paper is about a more general setting, we can restrict to the case of integers (undo the generalization!), to get a nice and illuminating proof.

**Lemma 1:** Any integer polynomial $f$ can be written in the "falling factorial basis" instead of the monomial basis. In other words, if $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^d a_k x^k$ where each $a_k$ is an integer, then we can also write $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^d c_k x^{\underline k}$$ for some integer coefficients $c_k$, where $x^{\underline k}$ means $x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$.

**Proof:** We have the expression $x^n = \sum_k {n \brace k} x^{\underline k}$ where ${n \brace k}$ is a Stirling subset number ("Stirling number of the second kind"), etc. See for instance Chapter 6 of the book *Concrete Mathematics*, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stirling_number&oldid=1011859619#As_change_of_basis_coefficients). $\blacksquare$

So from now on we'll write all polynomials in this basis.

**Lemma 2:** The polynomial $c_k x^{\underline k}$ vanishes identically mod $n$ (meaning that $c_k x^{\underline k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for all integers $x$) if and only if $c_k k!$ is divisible by $n$.

**Proof:** If $c_k x^{\underline k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for all $x$, then taking $x = k$ in particular gives $c_k k! \equiv 0 \pmod n$. For the other direction, if $c_k k!$ is divisible by $n$, then (for any integer $x$) note that $x^{\underline k}$ is a product of $k$ consecutive integers and is thus divisible by $k!$, which means that $c_k x^{\underline k}$ is divisible by $c_k k!$ which in turn is divisible by $n$. $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 3**: Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^d c_k x^{\underline k}$. Then $f$ vanishes identically mod $n$ (meaning that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for all integer $x$) if and only if each term $c_k x^{\underline k}$ vanishes identically mod $n$.

**Proof:** One direction is obvious: if each $c_k x^{\underline k}$ vanishes identically mod $n$, then so does their sum $f$. For the other direction, suppose $f \equiv 0 \pmod n$, and let $j$ be the smallest index such that $c_j x^{\underline j} \not\equiv 0 \pmod n$. Then,

- for $k < j$ we have $c_k x^{\underline k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ by definition of $j$,
- for $k > j$, by taking $x = j$ we see that $c_k j^{\underline k}$ includes a factor $0$ so $c_k j^{\underline k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

As $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod n$, this means (still looking at $x=j$) that the only remaining term $c_j j^{\underline j} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ as well, i.e. $c_j j!$ is divisible by $n$. This from Lemma 2 means that $c_j x^{\underline j} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for all $x$. $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 4:** $c_k k!$ is divisible by $n$ if and only if $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$ divides $c_k$.

**Proof:** A special case of "If $a$ divides $bc$, then $a/gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$", which can be [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904406/if-a-divides-bc-and-gcda-b-d-then-frac-a-d-divides-c) in many ways, say using the unique prime factorization.$\blacksquare$

This leads to a theorem characterizing all the polynomial functions mod $n$:

**Theorem:** Any polynomial function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $$f(x) = \sum_k c_k x^{\underline k} \qquad\text{ where }0 \le c_k < \frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}.$$

**Proof:** By the previous lemmas, note that changing one of the coefficients $c_k$ by a multiple of $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$ means adding a term which vanishes identically mod $n$, and thus does not change the function $f$. This means that each of the coefficients $c_k$ is determined only modulo $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$. $\blacksquare$

(Note that this is essentially a "structure theorem" for the abelian group (under addition) of polynomial functions mod $n$.)

Finally, as there are $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$ choices for each coefficient $c_k$, the number of distinct polynomial functions modulo $n$ is $$\prod_k \frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$$

---

**Edit.** Here's another proof I came up with, that's more computational and less "magic". It came up while trying to enumerate all possible "signatures" $(f(0), f(1), \ldots, f(n-1))$.

Specifically, suppose we are given a "signature" $(y_0, y_1, \ldots y_{n-1})$ and want to find a polynomial (or all polynomials) $f$ such that $f(0) \equiv y_0$ and $f(1) \equiv y_1$ and so on (all congruences are modulo $n$). By Lemma 1 from the proof above, we can suppose that the polynomial we are trying to find has been written in the basis of "falling factorial powers" $x^{\underline k}$, where $x^{\underline k}$ means $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1)$. That is, we can suppose that the polynomial we want is $$f(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^{\underline 2} + c_3 x^{\underline 3} + \ldots,$$ where we are trying to solve for the coefficients $c_0, c_1, \dots$.

This we can do iteratively, by considering the given values of $f(0), f(1), \dots$ in order:

- $f(0) = y_0$ is the same as $c_0 \equiv y_0$, which can always be "solved" for $c_0$, i.e. just set $c_0 \equiv y_0$.
- Having thus determined $c_0$, the next equation we were given, namely $f(1) = y_1$, is now the same as $c_0 + c_1 \equiv y_1$ or equivalently $c_1 \equiv y_1 - c_0$ which can always be solved for $c_1$, as $c_0$ is known.
- Next, $f(2) = y_2$ is the same as $c_0 + 2c_1 + 2c_2 \equiv y_2$ or equivalently $2c_2 \equiv y_2 - c_0 - 2c_1$ which (now that we have determined $c_0$ and $c_1$) can be solved for $c_2$ except in one case: if $n$ is even and the RHS is odd, then our congruence $2c_2 = \text{(an odd number)} \pmod n$ is impossible. So we need to impose a condition, namely: if $n$ is even then $y_2$ must be such that the RHS is also even. When $n$ is odd, any value mod $n$ will do for $y_2$, but when $n$ is even only half the values mod $n$ will do for $y_2$. In short, there are $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n, 2)}$ values for $y_2$ for which we can find $c_2$ to satisfy $f(2) = y_2$.
- Next, $f(3) = y_3$ is the same as $c_0 + 3c_1 + 6c_2 + 6c_3 \equiv y_3$ or equivalently $6c_3 \equiv y_3 - …$ which can be solved for $c_3$, for $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n, 6)}$ values of $y_3$.

And so on: in general $f(k) = y_k$ is the same as $k!c_k \equiv y_k - …$ which can be solved (for $c_k$) for $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$ values of $y_k$.

So the number of $(y_0, y_1, \ldots)$ that can possibly be the signatures of a polynomial (and thus also the number of polynomial functions) is:

$$\prod_{k \ge 0} \frac{n}{\gcd(n, k!)}$$

(Deep down there are of course some similarities between this proof and the previous one, but at least this version is something I could imagine having come up with by myself, with only the falling factorial basis idea.)

Comment: **Clearer:** $\,f(x)$ is the zero function $\!\bmod n\!\!\iff\!$ its coefs in [binomial basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642007/242) are all $\equiv 0\pmod{\!n},\,$ i.e. $\,f(x) = \sum_k b_k{x\choose k}\Rightarrow\,$ all $\,b_k\equiv 0\pmod{\!n}.\,$ There are very old results. $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque When writing up the question I found Kempner (1921) and Singmaster (1974) as the references (via OEIS). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3387540 for the zero function question. I'll think more about your hint, thank you.

Comment: @BillDubuque I tried working out your hint for a bit — I guess what we want to prove is that, for an integer-valued polynomial (in the sense of the other question, i.e. allowing non-integer coefficients) to correspond to a polynomial function (in the sense of this question, i.e. starting with integer coefficients), we must have each $b_k$ be a multiple of $k!$, and that is how the $n/\gcd(n, k!)$ factor will enter. It's not immediately obvious to me how to prove this cleanly (to get a cleaner/shorter proof than the second proof above), but will think about it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case is when $n$ is prime: Then the first $p$ monomials are independent and give us $n^n$ polynomial functions.

The next case of interest is when $n$ is a prime power, whci is left as an exercise to the reader. Once we have solved that, the full result follows using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The prime power case is the hard part that I wasn't able to see easily myself; could you explain it a bit?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR On polys of prime powers, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, I vaguely know about Hensel's lemma (had studied it at some point years ago) but I don't know how to apply it here. To ask more concretely, as I imagine I may be able to get the general idea from the example: how to prove that (A) if $n = p^2$, then the number of polynomial functions is $p^{3p}$? (B) If $n = p^3$ where $p \ge 3$, then the number of polynomial functions is $p^{6p}$? (Right now this answer covers the part that's easy for me and leaves the part that's hard for me as an exercise!)

Comment: I just posted an edit to the question clarifying that this answer is not the part of the question I have trouble with. :-) I didn't downvote obviously (thanks for answering!) but this initial version of this answer almost feels like a joke answer (or at least I find it funny), like the "draw the rest of the owl" meme!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I see your point. :) The actual story behind this answer was that late at night and fatigued, I started writing "primes and CRT" until I noticed the gap. I added the ominous "exercise" and went to bed, hoping to expand with a fresh brain today. -- Apparently way better answers have been added meanwhile

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen :-) Makes sense, thanks for answering… For my part, actually the reason I posted the comments about the gap is that at the time, this answer had as many votes as the question, so I worried a bit that everyone would think at a glance that the question was fully answered, and no one may look deeper / I may never get the explanation I was hoping for. :-) Meanwhile I was able to read one of the linked papers a bit more carefully and understand what's going on, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well bearing in must $m^k$ will eventually repeat.  Perhaps not with $m^{\phi(n)}\equiv m^0\equiv 1\pmod n$ but with some priliminary $k$ so that $m^{\phi(n) + k}\equiv m^k$.

So that gives us an upper bound $ax^k \equiv (a-n)x^{k-\phi(n)}$ so $(\phi(n) + 1)(n-1)$ is an upper bound.