# Finishing proof of: if $a\mid bc$ then $\frac a{\gcd(a, b)}\mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that $a$ divides $bc$ if and only if

$$\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)} \mid c$$

I go in the right direction first (i.e. if $a$ divides $bc$ then $\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)} \mid c$):

We want to show that $\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)} \cdot f \ = c$ for some $f \in \mathbb{Z}$. In other words, we want to show $a \cdot f = c \cdot \gcd(a, b)$ for some $f \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We know $a$ divides $bc$; this means that $ax = bc$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. We know that $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $a$ and $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $b$ by definition. This means that $\gcd(a, b) \cdot y = b$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

That is, $ax = \gcd(a, b) \cdot y \cdot c$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm almost there... just need to divide $y$ by both sides; but how do I prove that $\frac{x}{y}$ is an integer?!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Bezout's lemma, that $gcd(a,b) = ax + by$ for some integers $x$ and $y$?  It's often a powerful tool in this sort of problem.  Apply it to your desired equality:  $af = c \gcd(a,b)$, and you might see how to find your $f$.

Comment: If you write \gcd with a backslash, that not only prevents italicization but results in proper spacing in things like $a\gcd(b,c)$, between $a$ and $\gcd$.  It is standard usage.  I edited accordingly.  Also, I used \mid where appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks.

BarrySmith: The farthest I'm able to get with this is that:

WTS: $a(f-cx) = bcy$. Since we know that $az = bc$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, can I simply multiply both sides by $y$? i.e. $azy = bcy$, and I'm done?

Comment: Essentially.  You might be more convinced if you find a formula for $f$ in terms of $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$.  Since your goal is to show there exists an $f$ with a certain property, you can then substitute in your $f$ and check that it works.

Comment: Got it, thanks. In regards to the converse, I know that $ay = c(am + bn)$ for some $y, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and want to show that $ax = bc$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Am I correct in saying that this is equivalent to wanting to show that $axn = bcn$ for some $x, n \in \mathbb{Z}$? From here, we simplify $ay = c(am + bn)$ to $a(y - cm) = bcn$, and get that $y - cm = xn$. But how do we show that x an integer?

Comment: Heh, for this direction I think it is clearer to use the definition of GCD rather than Bezout's Lemma.  You assume that $ax=b \gcd(b,c)$ for some integer $x$, and you want to show that $ay = bc$ for some integer $y$.  If you multiply the first equality through by an appropriate integer, you will get one that looks like the second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $ a \mid bc $ then $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \mid c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508057/if-a-mid-bc-then-fraca-gcda-b-mid-c)