# If $n\mid at$, show that $\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}\mid t$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> If $n\mid at$, show that $\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}\mid t$.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, even though it seems very basic (I think I'm missing something fundamental here). What would be the way to show this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $ a \mid bc $ then $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \mid c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508057/if-a-mid-bc-then-fraca-gcda-b-mid-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the gcd of $a$ and $n$. Then $a=a_1d$ for some integer $a_1$, and $n=n_1d$ for some integer $n_1$, where $a_1$ and $n_1$ are **relatively prime**.

We are told that $n_1d$ divides $a_1dt$. It follows that $n_1$ divides $a_1t$. Since $n_1$ and $a_1$ are relatively prime, we conclude that $n_1$ divides $t$.

Comment: Great, thanks! The only part I don't understand would be, why would $a_{1}$ and $n_{1}$ (in $a=a_{1}d$, $n=n_{1}d$) be coprime?

Comment: If they are not coprime, suppose they have a common divisor $k\gt 1$. Then $kd$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $n$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the **greatest** common divisor of $a$ and $n$.

Comment: Very sorry, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps I should have filled in that detail in the answer.

Comment: ...or linked to a duplicate instead of answering ;-)